# Autocomplete Text box with Document Listener in Java

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener, documentfilter

I'm trying to make an autocomplete textbox for a program I'm writing. I have the logic down, but I'm having some trouble implementing it properly. First I tried it with a key listener, but that solution was a bit strange in the way that it handled multiple key presses at the same time. Then I tried DocumentListener which was far better, but doesn't allow me to edit the document from within the Listener because of a threading issue. I read something about DocumentFilter, but I can't find a single guide on how to use it. Is there a way of editing the doc from with documentListener? Or would you recommend DocumentFilter and if so, how do you use it??

Comment: You can edit the Document *cautiously* by putting the edits within a Runnable and queuing it onto the event thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`, but this is a dangerous thing to do. As for how to use a DocumentFilter, a lot of examples of this abound on this site, several of the written by me. Just [search the site](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+DocumentFilter) (click link).

Comment: Yeah I tried using invokeLater from within the Listener and it ran in an infinite loop. Any idea why that happened??

Comment: That's part of the danger -- when you change the document you invoke the listener, and if you change the document from within the listener, this can result in circular references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentListener should not be used to edit the document. Doing so would require a call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) and since DocumentListener detects changes to the document, any edits would result in an infinite loop. Best bet is to use DocumentFilter.